# Monitoring Tools for Druid and memSQL

Tags: newrelic, druid, singlestore

Is there a monitoring tool (like New Relic) to monitor DBs like Druid and memSQL? Did some research, but was not able to find relevant information.

Comment: Look this. It can be helpful: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/metrics.html

Answer (score 1):

For MemSQL:

As far as a third-party tool, MemSQL's monitoring components are compatible with Prometheus [metrics](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/).

Specifically, the [exporter](https://docs.memsql.com/v7.1/guides/cluster-management/monitoring/historical-monitoring/sudo/step-3/#memsql_exporter) component that's used to collect the data from the cluster is a Prometheus exporter and compatible with standard Prometheus metrics.

Note that MemSQL has a native [solution](https://docs.memsql.com/v7.1/guides/cluster-management/monitoring/historical-monitoring/sudo/step-1/) documented, which contains a MemSQL database that stores cluster monitoring data, along with MemSQL-based [Grafana Dashboards](https://docs.memsql.com/files/historical-monitoring-guide/historical-monitoring-dashboards.zip). However, if you want to use a third-party tool, Prometheus can also scrape the MemSQL exporter and store the metrics data from MemSQL.

Best,
RP

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer that I work for Imply.

There are a number of community [metrics](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/metrics.html) emitter extensions for a number of destinations, including [Kafka](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-contrib/kafka-emitter.html).  Which is cool as you can emit to Kafka and then send into Druid to do the analytics :)

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions.html#community-extensions

I've seen people build Grafana dashboard on top of those Druid metrics successfully.

Imply have a [monitoring and alerting tool](https://imply.io/product/imply-clarity) - it's using an extended set of the [metrics](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/metrics.html) that are natively emitted by Apache Druid.